# How to open print view via buttons on form view in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo

I am adding two buttons on a form view.
Print Form A
Print Form B
Existing code is generating issue:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/safe_eval.py", line 350, in safe_eval
return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
```

File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'model.name' object has no attribute 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ValueError: <class 'AttributeError'>: "'model.name' object has no attribute 'name'" while evaluating
```

"(object.state in ('draft','pending', 'done') and 'Firm - %s' % (object.name)) or 'Firm - %s' % (object.name)"

```
<report 
        id="action_report_form_a"
        string="FORM B"
        model="model.name" 
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        file="module_name.report_firms" 
        name="module_name.form_a"
        print_report_name="(object.state in ('draft','pending', 'done') and 'Firm - %s' % (object.name)) or 'Firm - %s' % (object.name)"
    />


    <report 
        id="action_report_form_b"
        string="FORM B"
        model="firms.registration" 
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        file="module_name.report_firms" 
        name="module_name.form_b"
        print_report_name="(object.state in ('draft','pending', 'done') and 'Firms - %s' % (object.name)) or 'Firms - %s' % (object.name)"
    />
@api.multi
def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
    docs = self.env['model.name'].browse(docids)
    return {
        'doc_ids': docs.ids,
        'doc_model': 'model.name',
        'docs': docs,
        'proforma': True
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `odoo_model = self.env['model.name']` then `odoo_model._name` (note the underscore) is the string with the model's name (`'name'` in your example) but if `doc_model` expects a true Odoo model, you try with `self.env.ref('model.name')` (or the proper XMLID)